# is RESTful useful for all websites?

Tags: rest

I have been studying RESTful web services for a while. My question is, despite how great it is, should every part of the website use RESTful style?

For example, yes I can create a User by POST->/user. If my website is similar to Twitter that after registration, users will be guided to a page to initiate their choice of broadcasts (kind of like on Twitter, you follow people). How do you name this initialization using RESTful style? Very difficult!

So is RESTful style for APIs only? Or should it be used throughout the site?

Comment: StackOverflow is RESTful. Google is RESTful. Your nearest high school's website is RESTful. See what I mean? If it uses a client-server protocol based on resource identifiers, methods, headers, and content bodies, it's probably RESTful.

Comment: OK...I found a way to work around my initiation problem: by creating a separate column in database to indicate if a user has initiated or not. Thanks :)